How to add a vent and move drain to other side of stud
I'm doing this bathroom in a house that was built in 1965. In the pictures immediately below, should I create a new stack out of the roof or could I attach it to the main one by the toilet?


I also need to move this drain over to the other side of the stud (on the right).


Where were the bath, basin and toilet before you began renovating and how were the drains and vents arranged?  What did you move?  Which way to the joists go, what kind and size are they?  What is above this room? -- If you run a vent from the (new?) basin location straight up the wall, can it find its way to the existing stack in the ceiling or attic above?  Your photos would help more if the joists were exposed, or some of them.

Gratuitous advice: If you are going to tile this room, or any part of it, get rid of the blue boxes and use metal ones with mud rings chosen the right size to be flush with the tile. This provides a stronger backing for the tile edges where they meet the boxes, so you can firmly mount outlets and switches, they won't be wobbly, the tile won't break, and the covers will rest flat and flush.

The advice from jay613 is solid, but be aware that metal boxes require specific grounding techniques. I've seen inspectors make a homeowner replace all the metal boxes in a rough-in with fiber-plastic for that reason.

As far as where the toilet vent is in relation to the vanity drain I'm standing in the door way on the picture with the window in it so its on my left. I have attic access.  I'm not tiling anything in this bathroom.  I also haven't moved the location of anything. The vanity will be different so im trying to center it under the light. Before I started this the vanity sink would vacuum out the p trap when drainjng. That's why I'm asking about the vent. I had a severe water leak from the shower and toilet causing really bad mold. I'm broke and doing the best I can. Thank you for any advice.

The vanity and toilet are at opposite corners.  You'd need at least an Air Admittance Valve at the vanity.  Pictures of the plumbing under the floor would help.  Why do you need to move the drain to the other side of the stud?  What problem will that solve?  Is it the easiest way to solve that problem?  Why?  My quick thought is that it would be easier to route to the existing drain than to move it.  Why have you discarded that option?

I get the impression that you haven't taken the [tour] as I suggested. Put all information in your question, please, not down here.

@isherwood what special grounding techniques do you mean? Can you give a quick pointer?

If the basin was siphoning and that's the main problem you need to solve, you can run a vent straight up to the attic and then over to the stack. It can run along the attic floor. It just needs a slight (specific) slope to drain water anywhere along its length.

If you have access to the attic, install a new vent for the basin. Once the new vent is up into the attic, you can connect it to the existing vent. Otherwise, you would need to look into using an air admittance valve if allowed in your location.
To relocate the drain for the vanity, use a sanitary tee and drill out the stud. Then, pipe the drain arm into the cavity. Offset the vent above the tee to avoid the electrical above. Be sure to use two 45° elbows to create the offset as the vent cannot run horizontally until 6” above the flood level of the vanity.


Is the vanity going to end at the stud next to the blue pipe?  If the vanity continues towards the wall the trap arm can be inside it rather than going through the stud.
